# How to rewrite methods to be a generic one?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm going to extract values from attributes of XML XElement, the types of these values are int, double, bool and string, below are the methods for this task, how can I rewrite them to be a generic one? And how to add constraints?

```
private int GetIntFromAttribute(XElement element, string attributeName)
{
    if (element.Attribute(attributeName) != null)
    {
        int.TryParse(element.Attribute(attributeName).Value, out var intValue);
        return intValue;
    }
    return 0;
}

private double GetDoubleFromAttribute(XElement element, string attributeName)
{
    if (element.Attribute(attributeName) != null)
    {
        double.TryParse(element.Attribute(attributeName).Value, out var doubleValue);
        return doubleValue;
    }
    return 0;
}

private bool GetBoolFromAttribute(XElement element, string attributeName)
{
    if (element.Attribute(attributeName) != null)
    {
        bool.TryParse(element.Attribute(attributeName).Value, out var boolValue);
        return boolValue;
    }
    return false;
}

private string GetStringFromAttribute(XElement element, string attributeName)
{
    if (element.Attribute(attributeName) != null)
    {
        return element.Attribute(attributeName).Value;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: There was a preview of [Generic Math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/) that included a discussion of being able to generically resolve `TryParse` methods. So far as I'm aware, this proposal hasn't made it into the language yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tests of the form `if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))` to call the correct `TryParse` method.

I assume you know where to put the `T` and `<T>`:  `private T GetFromAttribute<T>(XElement...`

Comment: Thanks Ron, one more question, how to add constraints to this generic method?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to keep different methods for different type when using `XXX.TryParse` methods.

You could have one method that accepts different types and then `switch`es on the type an calls an appropriate `TryParse`  but you cannot solve the `XXX.TryParse` problem purely with generics.